# Problem using variable loaded from TextField

Tags: gui-construction, variable

I'm trying to make a simple app, which loads some data via `TextFields` and then does something with that, but ...

```
Needs["GUIKit`"]
okt1 == PropertyValue[{"O1", "text"}]
mask1 == PropertyValue[{"M1", "text"}]
```

Of course `O1` and `M1` are simply names of `TextFields`. Then I want to use `BitAnd` with those two numbers which user should enter.

```
SetPropertyValue[{"siec1", "text"}, BitAnd[okt1, mask1]]
```

All these actions are performed by an inside script which starts to work when an user clicks a button.

My problem is why in `TextField` named `siec1` I see this:

```
BitAnd[GUIKit`Private`Script83`mask1, GUIKit`Private`Script83`okt1]
```

Instead of some value that I expect to see.
Of course when I use

```
SetPropertyValue[{"siec1", "text"}, 2]
```

Number 2 appears in `TextField` `siec1`.

How should I approach this problem ?

Whole code:

```
Needs["GUIKit`"];
ref = GUIRun[
    Widget["Panel",
        {
            Widget["Label", {"text" -> "Wprowadź adres IP:"}],
            {
                Widget["TextField", {"columns" -> 3}, Name -> "O1"],
                Widget["Label", {"text" -> "."}],
                Widget["TextField", {"columns" -> 3}, Name -> "O2"],
                Widget["Label", {"text" -> "."}],
                Widget["TextField", {"columns" -> 3}, Name -> "O3"],
                Widget["Label", {"text" -> "."}],
                Widget["TextField", {"columns" -> 3}, Name -> "O4"]
            },
            Widget["Label", {"text" -> "Wprowadź maskę"}],
            {
                Widget["TextField", {"columns" -> 3}, Name -> "M1"],
                Widget["Label", {"text" -> "."}],
                Widget["TextField", {"columns" -> 3}, Name -> "M2"],
                Widget["Label", {"text" -> "."}],
                Widget["TextField", {"columns" -> 3}, Name -> "M3"],
                Widget["Label", {"text" -> "."}],
                Widget["TextField", {"columns" -> 3}, Name -> "M4"]
            },
            Widget["Label", {"text" -> "                        "}],
            (***************************************************)
            (***************************************************)
            (***************************************************)
            Widget["Button", {"text" -> "Oblicz!",
                BindEvent["action",
                        Script[Przelicz[]] 
                     ],
                Script[
                        Przelicz[] := (
                        (*Pobranie wartosc z pol na formularzu*)
                            ref @okt1 == PropertyValue[{"O1", "text"}]
                            ref @okt2 == PropertyValue[{"O2", "text"}]
                            ref @okt3 == PropertyValue[{"O3", "text"}]
                            ref @okt4 == PropertyValue[{"O4", "text"}]

                            ref @mask1 == PropertyValue[{"M1", "text"}]
                            ref @mask2 == PropertyValue[{"M2", "text"}]
                            ref @mask3 == PropertyValue[{"M3", "text"}]
                            ref @mask4 == PropertyValue[{"M4", "text"}]



            SetPropertyValue[{"siec1", "text"}, BitAnd[okt1, mask1]]
                            SetPropertyValue[{"siec2", "text"}, 2]




                        )
                    ]
            }
            ],
            (***************************************************)
            (***************************************************)
            (***************************************************)
            Widget["Label", {"text" -> "                        "}],
            Widget["Label", {"text" -> "                        "}],
            Widget["Label", {"text" -> "Adres sieci:"}],
            {
                Widget["TextField", {"columns" -> 3, "enabled" -> True}, 
       Name -> "siec1"],
                Widget["Label", {"text" -> "."}],
                Widget["TextField", {"columns" -> 3, "enabled" -> False}, 
       Name -> "siec2"],
                Widget["Label", {"text" -> "."}],
                Widget["TextField", {"columns" -> 3, "enabled" -> False}, 
       Name -> "siec3"],
                Widget["Label", {"text" -> "."}],
                Widget["TextField", {"columns" -> 3, "enabled" -> False}, 
       Name -> "siec4"]
            },
            Widget["Label", {"text" -> "                        "}],
            Widget["Label", {"text" -> "Adres pierwszego hosta:"}],
            {
                Widget["TextField", {"columns" -> 3, "enabled" -> False}, 
       Name -> "phost1"],
                Widget["Label", {"text" -> "."}],
                Widget["TextField", {"columns" -> 3, "enabled" -> False}, 
       Name -> "phost2"],
                Widget["Label", {"text" -> "."}],
                Widget["TextField", {"columns" -> 3, "enabled" -> False}, 
       Name -> "phost3"],
                Widget["Label", {"text" -> "."}],
                Widget["TextField", {"columns" -> 3, "enabled" -> False}, 
       Name -> "phost4"]
            },
            Widget["Label", {"text" -> "                        "}],
            Widget["Label", {"text" -> "Adres ostatniego hosta:"}],
            {
                Widget["TextField", {"columns" -> 3, "enabled" -> False}, 
       Name -> "lhost1"],
                Widget["Label", {"text" -> "."}],
                Widget["TextField", {"columns" -> 3, "enabled" -> False}, 
       Name -> "lhost2"],
                Widget["Label", {"text" -> "."}],
                Widget["TextField", {"columns" -> 3, "enabled" -> False}, 
       Name -> "lhost3"],
                Widget["Label", {"text" -> "."}],
                Widget["TextField", {"columns" -> 3, "enabled" -> False}, 
       Name -> "lhost4"]
            },
            Widget["Label", {"text" -> "                        "}],
            Widget["Label", {"text" -> "Adres rozgłoszeniowy:"}],
            {
                Widget["TextField", {"columns" -> 3, "enabled" -> False}, 
       Name -> "brd1"],
                Widget["Label", {"text" -> "."}],
                Widget["TextField", {"columns" -> 3, "enabled" -> False}, 
       Name -> "brd2"],
                Widget["Label", {"text" -> "."}],
                Widget["TextField", {"columns" -> 3, "enabled" -> False}, 
       Name -> "brd3"],
                Widget["Label", {"text" -> "."}],
                Widget["TextField", {"columns" -> 3, "enabled" -> False}, 
       Name -> "brd4"]
            },
            Widget["Label", {"text" -> "                        "}],
            Widget["Label", {"text" -> "                        "}],

            (***************************************************)
            (***************************************************)
            Widget["Button", {"text" -> "Zapisz do pliku!",
                BindEvent["action",
                        Script[ZapiszDoPliku[]] 
                     ],
                Script[
                        ZapiszDoPliku[] := (
                            lol123 = 1


                        )
                    ]
            }
            ],
            (***************************************************)
            (***************************************************)


        }, Name -> "Okno"]
   ];
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: I receive error messages when I run your first two lines of code.  `PropertyValue` needs more arguments: According to the documentation, `PropertyValue[{obj,item},name]`.  Also, do you really mean `==` in those equations?

Comment: In fact `PropertyValue[{"M1", "text"}]` has red color, but I can't see any error. I'm using it like in this [example](http://wolfram.com/xid/0ux2mpsnwzl7kmfo-hm1p0) . And if I use `=` I get error `Set::write: Tag Times in 255 mask1 is Protected`.

Comment: Your Question does not appear to show all your essential code, so it is difficult to suggest improvements.  Also, once I add Needs["GUIKit`"], the error goes away.

Comment: I added whole code. I need to load these 8 values from `O1, O2, O3, O4, M1, M2, M3, M4`, do some work with them and paste result in other TextFields. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: `Print[NumberQ[PropertyValue[{"O1", "text"}]]]` shows `False`. Is it possible, that I can't do anything with that because this is String type variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it. I can't find simplier method, but this one actually works for me.

I don't create variables for every single `TextField`. While using `BitAnd[]` for example I'm doing it this way:

```
SetPropertyValue[{"siec1", "text"},
                    ToString[BitAnd[ToExpression[PropertyValue[{"O1", "text"}]],
                                ToExpression[PropertyValue[{"M1", "text"}]]]]]
```

Thanks everyone for help.